# YII fails to read BIGINT in Postgres 9.4. Silently converts to MAX_INT. Works in 9.5

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, yii2

I have different database versions in DEV and PROD. DEV is using Postgres 9.5, while PROD is using version 9.4. It works in DEV, but not PROD. I only want to read the value of a BIGINT field. They are silently limited to MAX_INT! I already set the field in 'number' in the rules of the model. How do I read the correct value?

#### What steps will reproduce the problem?

```
class KwController extends \yii\console\Controller {

  public function actionTest() {
    $accounts = Account::find()->all();
    foreach ($accounts as $account) {
      echo "$account->google_id\n";
      //echo $account->google_id.PHP_EOL;
      //printf("%s\n", $account->google_id);
    }
  }

class Account extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  public function rules()
  {
      return [
          [['google_id', 'bing_id'], 'number'],
          [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
      ];
  }


dev=# \d account
                                  Table "public.account"
  Column   |          Type          |                      Modifiers
-----------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer                | not null default nextval('account_id_seq'::regclass)
 name      | character varying(255) |
 google_id | bigint                 |
 bing_id   | bigint                 |


prod=> \d account
                                  Table "public.account"
  Column   |          Type          |                      Modifiers
-----------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer                | not null default nextval('account_id_seq'::regclass)
 name      | character varying(255) |
 google_id | bigint                 |
 bing_id   | bigint                 |


dev=# select * from account;
 id |   name    | google_id  | bing_id
----+-----------+------------+---------
  1 | Test      | 1304682651 |
  2 | Account 2 | 2712796608 |


prod=> select * from account;
 id |   name    | google_id  | bing_id
----+-----------+------------+---------
  1 | Account 1 | 3797444208 |
  2 | Account 2 | 8817806877 |
  3 | Account 3 | 3199585540 |
  4 | Account 4 | 1596230720 |
  5 | Account 5 | 1389831585 |


$ /usr/sbin/postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.5.2


prod=> \c
psql (9.5.2, server 9.4.4)
```

#### What is the expected result?

I expect the output to be

```
3797444208
8817806877
3199585540
1596230720
1389831585
```

#### What do you get instead?

Notice that DEV has a value larger than MAX_INT, yet it works OK. Whenever PROD has a value larger than MAX_INT, it only prints MAX_INT instead.

```
$ yii kw/test
1304682651
2712796608


$ YII_ENV=prod yii kw/test
2147483647
2147483647
2147483647
1596230720
1389831585
```

#### Additional info

Yii 2.0.7, PHP 5.6.19, Windows/Cygwin (DEV), Heroku (PROD)

I also entered a bug just in case: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/11286

Comment: This sounds like a hardware, OS or PHP limitation in PROD. Try `echo PHP_INT_MAX` you should be getting two different results in DEV and PROD.

Comment: @D.Mill DEV: `$ php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'
2147483647` PROD: `heroku run "php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'"
Running php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;' on project... up, run.1331
9223372036854775807`. Nevertheless, I am running the same PHP locally for both cases above and only pointing to a different DB. The PHP version in PROD shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use this

```
$accounts = Account::find()->select(['*', 'google_id' => 'cast(google_id as varchar)'])->all();
```

But only under protest. I don't like it!

Warning, if you use schema cache, you may have to way for it to expire before you can try changes.

```
'enableSchemaCache' => true,
```